# axios response object in finally callback is undefined

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios, es6-promise

I am using axios in one of my Vue.js project. I am performing some operations no matter if an API call fails or completes. I came to know about `finnaly()` method.
It is being executed after the API request either fails or succeeds.
  But I am not getting response object in callback given to finally.

For Example:

```
axios()
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response); // response object defined
  //handle response on success
  return response
}).finally((response) => {
  console.log(response); // response object undefined
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Promise.finally method does not give arguments to the callback

Read MDN [ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally ]

You could use .then again to get the response.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by including polyfill.finally script:

```
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=Promise.prototype.finally" defer></script>
```